# Configure Back Button to Skip First View

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app with a title screen. When the app first starts, I have an onCreate method that contains the following code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.title_screen);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        }
    }, 2000);
```

When I run my app and press the back button while on the main_screen layout, it closes the app (as it should). However, when I reopen the app, it displays the title_screen layout for two seconds again even though the app is already running. How can I prevent this?

Comment: When we use thread in java,  after the thread finish it work, it will "die". Handler is a way that allowed you use your thread all the time. Can you explain some detail, it be reopened and then display title_screen what happen after that?

Comment: After I reopen the app, it displays the title screen again for seemingly the same amount of time then switches back to the main screen.

Comment: got your point. I think this is because you didn't end the handler process at the previous time you open the app, so the handler still working. I think you can create a "flag" for this function, I'll post it in answer and you can try it.

Comment: hey, your question is a little ambiguous.
so, WHAT RESULT DO YOU WANT?

Comment: Smith Lee- I'm not really sure which part is ambiguous. I want the app to go directly to the main_screen view when it reopens after being closed by the back button.

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent the delay appearing again when resumed:

```
private static boolean flag = false;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!flag){
           setContentView(R.layout.title_screen);
           final Handler handler = new Handler();
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
           }
       }, 2000);
       flag = true;

   } else { 
       setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
   }

 }
```

Btw, if your app was on background and it is calling onCreate again while being resumed, it means that it is killed by the OS. Therefore it is normal to have the initial delay again.

What I would do is to implement two different activities first one showing title_screen and the second which is started after 2s should show your main screen.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code I can see that you ALWAYS start with `title_screen` then after 2s, you change to `main_screen`. Therefore, when you press `back`, that means you finish your `activity`. When you re-open your app, `onCreated` is called again, and it run every line of code as the previous opening.Of course, there's no difference in 2 times you open your app. To overcome it, I recommend to use `SharedPreference` to store the flag to check `main_screen` or `title_screen`.